# Reading parts of a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, I want to create a code that would read a part of a python file.
For example, the file I want to read had

```
matrix1 =[[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]]

matrix2 = [[[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]]

matrix3 = [[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]]

....
```

Each group of matrices is separated by a blank line.
I want to only read the contents of matrix 1 and then store it in a variable. Then I want to only read the contents of matrix 2 and store it in a variable. Same thing for matrix 3.

My code -

```
open('file.py')
matrix1 = read'file.py')
```

My code doesn't work because now it reads the entire file instead of just the matrices, obviously.
What can I do so that my output is 3 different nested matrices that i can store seprately into different variables.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```py
from file import matrix1

# or

from file import * as data

# and then access the data like this:
data.matrix1
```

Don't try to actually open the file manually, and then parse the data, if the file already is a python file. This also works for other stuff in your python file like classes and functions.

Comment: I never thought of that. Thank u, ur brilliant. Im actually pretty stupid for overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

with that code stored in the example file `file.py` you can do the following

```
exec(open('file.py').read())

print(matrix1)
```

```
[[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]]
```

> note that this can be unsafe if a user has access to the contents of file.py